# What to do if more than one view needs to link to a destroy action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure what to do here.   I have two scaffolds:  Groups and Users.  In two different Group views I'm listing group users and calling the Destroy method of the users_controller.

Since a 2nd view is now calling the destroy action, I need some way of detecting what view called the Destroy action because I need a different redirect and custom flash notice for each of the two group views.

Is there a simple way of solving this, or would the solution be something like making a copy of the Destroy method and mapping a new route for it?

-thanks!

edit:  maybe this is a stupid idea, but I was thinking...  For the two involved views, what if I stored their view names in the session when the views are generated (as a flag for the Destroy action to know which view to redirect to and what custom flash notice to send back)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the parameter with the links and check those parameters in your action.

Like ,

```
link_to "Delete", :controller => "groups", :action => "destroy", :pass_par => "view1"

link_to "Delete", :controller => "groups", :action => "destroy", :pass_par => "view2"
```

Controller:

```
def destroy
  if params[:pass_par] == "view1"
    redirect_to view1 
  else
    redirect_to view2
  end
end
```

Comment: That syntax for link_to didn't work for me.  What I'm using in one of the views looks like this (I haven't figured out how to pass an extra parameter):  <%= link_to 'remove me', '/users/' + group.user_id, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete  %>

Comment: The variable `:pass_par` or something nicer like `:return_to` should be part of the url, not the options hash, so to speficy this correctly you can use format like either `<%= link_to('remove me', user_path(group.user_id, :return_to => "page1"), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete) %>` (assuming you are using named/restful routes) or with the syntax given in the answer specifying the url as a hash `<%= link_to("Delete", {:controller => "groups", :action => "destroy", :pass_par => "view2"}, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete) %>`

Comment: Awesome thank you.   I think I was being an idiot and needed to map a route with the extra parameter.

Answer (score -1):

The destroy method is not very long, so yes, go ahead and copy it.

If it looks like this:

```
  # DELETE /users/1
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to users_url
  end
```

It should be not repeating yourself at all, and it will make your code simpler to read in the end.

Comment: Duplicating logic is never a good idea, one of the main principles is to keep your code DRY

Comment: I really like this way of doing it and went with it (duplicate code aside).  I actually haven't had to deal with mapping a route yet but I figured it out and everything is working - thank you.

Comment: Cool. I think you need to be concern about the DRYness of your code, but not to a extend of adding a if to avoid duplicating a line. 
Welcome to stackoverflow! When you pick the answer that responded better, hit the "V" so you spread the love of reputation! :)